# Reindex Taxonomy URLs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a list of terms all with assigned URLs already.
When I change the term and the URL, it is not updating.

I feel like there's a cache or reindexing needed ?

Comment: Did you change the URLs yourself? How/where do you change the term and the URL? Please add all the relevant information about your configuration. Did you flush cache under Configuration > Development > Performance?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have change the taxonomy term name manually or the url alias?
If you only have change the name you must to check the field "Generate automatic URL alias" is checked to change the url automatically.

If is checked or you have change URL alias manually then clear cache in /admin/config/development/performance

I hope that helps.